# Access in a folder is denied

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for a file in my computer.
Using this way

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
            My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments,
                    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, UploadControl.FileName)
                fullPath.Add(foundFile)
            Next
```

But in some subdirectories access does not allow throwing error `access is denied`
I do not want to manage the error but go to the next subdirectory.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Short Answer: **Don't use `GetFiles()`.**  Probably not what you want to hear.  You need to build your own function that recursively iterates over all the folders and files so you can gracefully catch the exceptions and move on.  If you Google it, you'll find tons of posts on how to do this...

Comment: @ Idle_Mind It is also a solution that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by overcoming the error with `try - catch`
When the error is trap it then send the it to the end of the loop of subdirectories
Thank you all for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Try start the app as admin.

If the solution is work change the app to default start as admin

Comment: It's not exactly what to do now.
But what will the application users do?
You see I can not give them instructions to change to `admin` just do not.
It must somehow find something to overcome it and not to stand there ... to the problem waiting a solution. I just don't care for solution.